# Text to Speech setLanguage() does not work

Tags: android

I am using Text to Speech.

When I set the language using

```
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
mTts.setLanguage(Locale.UK)
```

I always get an American accent.

The only way to fix this is by changing the default language setting in the Android system.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SOLVED

Instead of putting it inside onActivityResult() put it inside onInit(int status) and it works

Comment: Weird behavior. It seems that TTS really needs to be initialized completely before setting the language.

Comment: It's not working for me in the onInit(int status) method.. I'm going mad!

Answer (score 0):

There is another case which the language is not installed on tts and the device doesn't have access to net I have seen it on **KitKat**. In that case tts doesn't change the language, It won't give `getAvailableLanguages()` and works only on the default language. 
You can see that by calling `getLanguage()` after you assigned the new language